# Argument of send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I put this in my Rails controller

```
send_file('/public/images/rails.png')
```

but it gives error

```
Cannot read file /public/images/rails.png
```

even though the file is there. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing the first slash: `send_file('public/images/rails.png')`.

Comment: Now it says `Cannot read file public/images/rails.png`

Comment: have you sufficient permissions for the folder?

Comment: @Moe Yes, of course! It's the `public` folder of my Rails project. I have permission to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/images/rails.png")
```